# Display the amount of items the search engine has indexed

Tags: search, search-results

I have been trying to figure out how to display (somewhat like Google) how many items the Sharepoint search-engine is searching amongst, and display it next to the search-field.

Does anyone know how to do this - or maybe have some tips to point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of-the-box - just by using the User Interface (e.g. Web Parts) i don't believe is possible particularly for large result sets (you will always get a "estimative" count of RESULTS - see here for more details - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2009/02/20/handling-paging-and-total-results-count-in-sharepoint-custom-results-page.aspx).

On the other hand, you could see as part of the Search Scope how many items are included, or via SP-CA how many have been crawled.

Programatically however you could very easily reach your current Search Scope total results (or Shared Scopes) or even the Search Service Application data and create a simple web part (or extend the out-of-the-box CoreSearchResults) to display such information.

Comment: That certainly helps me. TotalRows is probably what I need.