# i need to find the total indexed items per day and show it as weekly report. Please help with the c# API

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-addin

As a part of c# sharepoint 2013 development activity, i need to find the total indexed items(searchable items) per day and show it as weekly report.

I checked here 
[Display the amount of items the search engine has indexed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37606/display-the-amount-of-items-the-search-engine-has-indexed/86852#86852)

but answer is not clear to me. Please help with the c# API

Answer (score 2):

There is out of the box functionality that you can use.

For information regading search you can [View search diagnostics in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219611.aspx)

SharePoint 2013 provides the following reports about crawl health:

• Crawl Rate 
• Crawl Latency
• Crawl Queue
• Crawl Freshness
• Content Processing Activity
• CPU and Memory Load
• Continuous Crawl

For information about total indexed items see the [Overview of the crawl health report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219611.aspx#proc2)

In central admin you can find the Crawl Health Report using the following page

```
_admin/search/crawlhealthreports.aspx
```

On MSDN there is a guide [Getting Started with the SharePoint Server Search Administration Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628253.aspx) for accessing the search administration

[Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.aspx) namespace reference

[CrawlLog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.crawllog.aspx)
[CrawlLog.GetCrawledUrlCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.crawllog.getcrawledurlcount.aspx)

Comment: Is indexed items count and searchable items are same? When i reset the index, only searchable items on search admin page becomes 0. In the crawl rate report and other reports the data has not changed. Please give me the more information...

Comment: Crawl rate is the crawl activity, the items crawled, index is the total items

Comment: I checked the health reports, but none of them provides the Indexed items or total. Crawl rate report has only crawled items count. please give me an idea to get the indexed items total using  c# api

Comment: added some code links